# Validation errors not disappearing after correction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor

My MVC Model is like this 2 required fields and 2 optional required fields [ If HasOptional property is true , then only last 2 fields are mandatory]

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Required...")]
public string Title { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage="Required...")]
public string Publisher { get; set; }

public bool HasOptional{get;set;}

public string OptTitle { get; set; }
public string OptPublisher { get; set; }
```

So in Controller POST action i did was

```
if(model.HasOptional)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(model.OptTitle)))
    {
      ModelState.AddModelError.Add("OptTitle","required....");
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(model.OptPublisher)))
    {
      ModelState.AddModelError.Add("OptPublisher","required....");
    }
}
```

And if the property is null i gets the Validation messages in view back without any issues.But my question is 
If i am filling OptTitle / OptPublisher in View and change the focus of textbox , still i can see the validation messages on screen . **Is  there any way to disappear the Validation after filling the info [ like the default behaviour for first 2 properties  Title and Publisher]**

Comment: You are creating server side errors only. In order to have client side error validation (so that they disappear) you need to create client side rules that can be used by jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive. I suggest you look at [foolproof's](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` attribute which will handle both server side and client side validation

Comment: RequiredIf can use only for bool property right?In my actual case i have to use an Enumerator Property [which might took 3 possible values].In question i used it as bool only for simplicity

Comment: Foolproof has numerous validation attributes you can look at. In your case (I assume you want `OptTitle` and `OptPublisher` to be required if `HasOptional=true`), adding `RequiredIf("HasOptional", ErrorMessaage=....)]` to both `OptTitle` and `OptPublisher` will work

Comment: How can i make a RequiredIf to a specific value .Like if HasOptional is "abc" then i need to make OptPublisher  as Required

Comment: But property `HasOptional` is a bool so not sure I understand. But there are others like `RequiredIfRegExMatch` that you could use (I think its `[RequiredIfRegExMatch("HasOptional", "abc", Error...)]`. And of course you can always implement your own.

Comment: ?In my actual case i have to use an Enumerator Property [which might took 3 possible values].In question i used it as bool only for simplicity.Now i got how to use it . Thanks for guiding in correct direction

Comment: Always post the real code!

Answer (score 0):

Add clientside validation and write it manually or use jQuery unobtrusive validation which will be guided by your data annotation attributes.

If you go down the unobtrusive approach make sure you have the script included (comes with MVC) and enabled in the web config.

A related tutorial at:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/577937/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Validating-Model-Data-and

Comment: OP is already using unobtrusive validation which is clear from the bold text

Comment: unobtrusive  i am using but point is that i am adding ModelError from Controller for few properties [ which are conditional required only ], so the question is to achieve same effect for those 2 conditional items too